# Upper case only on specific characters in python string/list

Tags: python, string, list, uppercase

I am learning python list and string functions. I need to write a specific function. My function returns correctly the Else task. However, I am not able to capitalize only the first and last letter of each word in the given sentence. Thank you for your help, I can only use basic functions as given in the hints.

Here is the task:
**If** the given sentence starts with *, capitalizes the first and last letters of each word in the sentence, and returns the sentence without *.
**Else**, joins all the words in the given sentence, separating them with a comma, and returns the result.

For example
if we call capitalize_or_join_words("*i love python"), we'll get "**I LovE PythoN**" in return.
If we call capitalize_or_join_words("i love python"), we'll get "**i,love,python**" in return.
If we call capitalize_or_join_words("i love    python  "), we'll get "**i,love,python**" in return.

Hints:
The **startswith()** function checks whether a string starts with a particular character. The **capitalize()** function capitalizes the first letter of a string.The **upper()** function converts all lowercase characters in a string to uppercase. The **join()** function creates a single string from a list of multiple strings

```
def capitalize_or_join_words(sentence):

if sentence.startswith('*'):
    s = sentence.replace('*','')
    s2 = s.split()
    
    s3 = []

    for word in s2:
        s3 += word.capitalize()
    
    temp = ",".join(s3)
    sentence_revised = temp
    
else:
    
    s = sentence.split()
    sentence_revised = ",".join(s)

return sentence_revised
```

Comment: You should treat the last character separately: cut it down from the string, make it upper case (as it's going to be a single-character string, you can use any of the two functions offered), and append it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
def capitalize_word(word):
    if not word:
        return ''
    if len(word) < 3:
        return word.upper()
    return word[0].capitalize() + word[1:-1] + word[-1].capitalize()

def capitalize_or_join_words(sentence):
    if sentence.startswith('*'):
        words = sentence.replace('*', '').split()
        return ' '.join(capitalize_word(word) for word in words)

    words = sentence.split()
    return ','.join(words)
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [1]: string = "My name is amir saleem"
   ...: ' '.join([i[0].upper()+i[1:-1] + i[-1].upper() for i in string.split()])
Out[1]: 'MY NamE IS AmiR SaleeM'
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this code answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def capital(strings):
    if strings.startswith("*"):
        strings = strings.replace("*", "")
        strings = result = strings.title()
        result = ""
        for word in strings.split():
            result += word[:-1] + word[-1].upper() + " "
        return result[:-1]
    else:

        strings = strings.split()
        result = ",".join(s)
        return result
```